# Is the Electric field around a loop on conducting wire always constant?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a wire is subject to some arbitrarily changing magnetic flux inducing an electric field within, what is the E-field equal to?

$\oint \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl} = -\frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dS} = |\vec{E}| \cdot \sum dimensions_{wire} $

Comment: It is certainly *not* constant in general, especially when the magnetic field is not homgenous. But for applications in circuits you are only interested in the voltage (i.e. $\int d\vec l \cdot \vec E$).

Comment: Your notation $\sum dimensions_{wire}$ is confusing to me. Also, as @SebastianRiese said, the electric field is not in general constant. You could, however, say $-\frac{d}{dt} \int \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dS} = |\vec{E}|_{\text{average}} \cdot L$ where $L$ is the total length of the wire.